# RuntimeError: Task got Future < Future Pending> attached to a different loop

Tags: flask, get, flask-sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, asyncpg

In the below code, I have created a route to get the list of dictionaries containing the author details from the postgres sql.

when I hit the endpoint from the browser for the first time it gives me the correct output, but when I reload the page I get the error: "Task got Future object attached to a different loop", and then when I reload the page for the second time I was getting the error "cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress".

```
engine = create_async_engine(database_URI, pool_size=30, echo = True)
async_session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False, class=AsyncSession)

@author_routes.route('/authors')
class Author_Modification(MethodView):
    async def get(self):
        try:
           async with async_session() as session:
               query = select(Author)
               get_authors = await session.execute(result)
               res = get_authors.scalers().all()
               author_schema = AuthorSchema(many=True)
               authors = author_schema.dump(res)
          await session.close()
          return response_with(resp.SUCCESS_200)
       except Exception as e:
          return response_with(resp.SERVER_ERROR_404)
```

I am stuck with this issue for days but could not able to come out with an appropriate code.

I even tried to bound the function in an event loop so that the event loop only run till the function gives the output using

```
async def get_output(self):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(self.get())
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

but after this I got the RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running.

I even tried to create multiple connection by adding

```
async def get(self):
    async with asyncpg.create_pool(host=config.host, database=config.database, user =config.user,      password=config.password, port = 5432) as pool:
        async with pool.acquire() as con:
            try:
               async with async.session() as session:
                   query = select(Author)
                   get_authors = await con.fetch(query)
                   res = get_authors.scalers().all()
                   ......
```

to the get route but got the error: "object of type 'Select' has no len()"

Comment: Did you investigate the traceback that showed you the error "Task got future object attached to a different loop"?  When I debug a Python program I always start there.  I think it's a much better approach than re-writing your program in several different ways, without first understanding why your first approach didn't work.  Why don't you post the traceback and see if someone here can spot something?

Comment: You will get this error if your view is called in different threads each time. You did not post how you are running this code, but that is certainly the case.  Check your flask-docs and make sure you are serving your views from a single thread. I will post an answer that should ensure a different connection per thread instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like whatever you are using to serve your app is using several threads in the same process, and then running an asyncio loop in each of them.

Keeping your objects that are tied to loops in thread local variables should work - so, here is a modification for your initial code that should do it:

```
import threading

db_connections = threading.local()

def get_sessionmaker():
    if not hasattr(db_connections, "engine")
         db_connections.engine = create_async_engine(database_URI, pool_size=30, echo = True)
    if not hasattr(db_connections, "sessionmaker"):
         db_connections.sessionmaker = sessionmaker(bind=db_connections.engine, autoflush=False, class=AsyncSession)
    return db_connections.sessionmaker

@author_routes.route('/authors')
class Author_Modification(MethodView):
    async def get(self):
        try:
           async with get_sessionmaker()() as session:
               query = select(Author)
               get_authors = await session.execute(result)
               res = get_authors.scalers().all()
               author_schema = AuthorSchema(many=True)
               authors = author_schema.dump(res)
          # await session.close()  # <- I don't think you need this, since you are using a `with` block for the session.
          return response_with(resp.SUCCESS_200)
       except Exception as e:
          return response_with(resp.SERVER_ERROR_404)
```

Maybe the engine itself would not need to be thread-local - also, if you need it elsewhere, you can create another function, or modify the one above, to return it.

Comment: Actually this particular route takes a lot of time to return response, and if in real world scenario to many user try to access this route simultaneously then it would cause massive delay, thus I was trying to make this route async so that multiple request can be handled concurrently. But this code could not able to create large variation in response time. I am sending 250 request using ThreadPoolExecutor but only couple of second variation was there in response